# Why toString() is called automatically from constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class, tostring

I have an abstract class called `Expression` which represents the result of a math expression and the class `AtomicExpression` which represents an operand of a math expression which extends `Expression`. `AtomicExpression` class has the method `toString()`. Inexplicably, whenever I initialize an instance of `AtomicExpression` then `toString()` is called automatically even though I didn't call it explicitly. I don't understand how this can be.

Originally I noticed that `String.format` from `toString()` was returning an error before `toString()` would be called, so I decided to add `System.out.println` inside `toString()` to see from console each time a call would be made to `toString()`.

This is the code:

```
public abstract class Expression {
    private double expression;

    public Expression(double expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }
    public abstract double calculate();

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Expression e = (Expression) o;
        return this.expression == e.expression;
    }
}

public class AtomicExpression extends Expression {
    private double operand;
    private static final String BLANK = "";

    public AtomicExpression(double operand) {
        super(operand);
        this.operand = operand;
    }

    public double calculate() {
        return this.operand;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s;

        if(this.operand == (int) this.operand) { //the operand is an integer
            //s = String.format("%d", this.operand);
            System.out.println("this.operand == (int) this.operand");
            s = BLANK + this.operand;
            return s;
        } else { //the num is a double
            s = BLANK + this.operand;
            return s;
        }

    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicExpression a = new AtomicExpression(5);
        //System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think toString was called?

Comment: @Eran I see from console that the message "this.operand == (int) this.operand" is printed and this message comes from my `toString()`

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't show that, at least just by compiling and running. Are you sure this isn't because you're running in a debugger? How are you executing this code?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am running a debugger from Intellij. Can debugger cause this?

Comment: Quite possibly, if you're looking at local variables etc. Try running without debugging.

Comment: Debuggers usually call toString to display the content of a variable

Comment: @JonSkeet I had no idea that debuggers can call methods without them actually being called explicitly

Comment: @Yos In Java Whenever we try to print the Object reference then internally toString() method is invoked. If we did not define toString() method in your class then Object class toString() method is invoked otherwise our implemented/Overridden toString() method will be called.